# правописание названий

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как писать разговорные названия учебных заведений. К примеру, Высшая школа экономики - "Вышка", МГТУ им. А. Н. Косыгина - "Косыга" и т. д. Вроде бы и кавычки излишни, но словообразование этих названий уж очень "народное"...

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую ориентироваться на то, как пишутся

***Щепка*** (Высшее театральное училище имени М. С. Щепкина),

***Щука*** (Театральный институт им. Бориса Щукина),

***Гнесинка*** (Государственное музыкальное училище имени Гнесиных),

***Ленинка*** (Российская библиотека им. В. И. Ленина, ныне Российская государственная библиотека),

***Плешка*** (Российский экономический университет имени Г. В. Плеханова)...

Туда же и ***Косыга*** (Московский государственный текстильный университет им. А. Н. Косыгина).

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки не зависят не того, к какому стилю принадлежит название - разговорному или книжному.

Постановка кавычек зависит от вида названий, которые можно разделить на две большие группы:
Составные названия, не являющиеся условными, – реальные собственные имена (в терминологии А. В. Суперанской). В таких названиях все слова употребляются в прямом значении. Кавычками такие названия не выделяются; в них пишется с прописной буквы первое слово и входящие в состав наименования имена собственные. Например: ***Государственный Русский музей, Останкинский музей творчества крепостных, Московский драматический театр на Малой Бронной***.

2. Условные (символические) названия, заключаемые в кавычки.

***Реальные собственные имена и условные наименования различаются прежде всего синтаксической сочетаемостью. Ср.: Большой театр, Театр сатиры, Театр на Юго-Западе – это реальные собственные имена, в них присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость, кавычки не нужны. Но: театр «Современник», театр «Школа современной пьесы» – условные наименования, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым словом. Они заключаются в кавычки. Аналогично: парк Дружбы, но: парк «Сокольники», Коммунистическая партия Российской Федерации, но: партия «Яблоко» и т. д.***

**Обратите внимание:** реальные собственные имена тоже могут употребляться в сочетании с родовым наименованием (чаще всего – обозначением организационно-правовой формы) **и при этом заключаться в кавычки, но при употреблении без родового наименования они, в отличие от условных названий, пишутся без кавычек, ср.:** М**осковская типография № 2 и ОАО «Московская типография № 2», Государственная академия славянской культуры и образовательное учреждение «Государственная академия славянской культуры», Город воинской славы и почетное звание «Город воинской славы»,**

Подробнее здесь: [В каких случаях нужны кавычки?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1)